# Choosing 3 (or n) observation from given index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm trying to take the 3 highest observations for each index. For instance, I have

```
census=pd.Series([2000,4432,5435,43252,63463,423432,3525,54353,6363]) 
census.index=['AL','AL','AL','AL','AK','AK','AK','AK','AK']
```

I want to get 3 highest observation for AL and AK and get it as a different series. Thanks.

Comment: Start with `s = census.groupby(level=0).nlargest(3)` and then figure out how to fix the result yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question, but I don't know how to mark this as the correct answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: At least don't accept the other answer until they fix their code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `census.groupby(level=0).nlargest(3)`

Thanks @coldspeed

Comment: `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'high'` what is this, is this actually working for you?

Comment: No, that's still wrong? That doesn't give you the largest observations either.

Comment: Indeed, I was using a sorted dataframe.